# Replacing symbols with lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a simple dataframe that I'd like to replace string values. However, I got syntax error and I cannot spot where did I do wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col':["('Low', 'Zero')", "('False', 'True')"]}
d = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
    col
0   ('Low', 'Zero')
1   ('False', 'True')
```

Replace values with lambda

```
d['col'].apply(lambda x: "('Low', 'Zero')" if x == "('Low', 'Zero')")
```

```
    d['col'].apply(lambda x: "('Low', 'Zero')" if x == "('Low', 'Zero')")
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: [Python]? ......

Comment: (Turns out the code is already incorrect but) it's best if you include a `import pandas` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `a if condition else b`. Your code is missing `else b` part

```
d['col'].apply(lambda x: "('Low', 'Zero')" if x == "('Low', 'Zero')" else "(nothing)" )
```